# How to programmatically show focus visual of a control in mouse click

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

When a certain control in my uwp app get focused (when it's `GotFocus` event is fired), I want to show it's focus visuals. Now, reading the doc, I know that by default it's set up to show only when using a controller or keyboard, but I also want to show it when a user focus on it by clicking on it, (or tapping on it in a touch device). 
Is it possible?

The focus visual works perfectly with Tab key of keyboard.

I have set the `UseSystemFocusVisuals` to true.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I found it. 
It should have worked after setting the `Application.FocusVisualKind` to `Reveal` in *App.xaml*, but for some reason, it generates **XBF error, property not found**.

So, I had to set the property in the constructor of *App.xaml.cs*.

Then, in the control which I want to show focus visual, I have set the following properties:

```
<UserControl
    IsTabStop="True"
    UseSystemFocusVisuals="True"
    PointerPressed="UserControl_PointerPressed"
    AllowFocusOnInteraction="True"/>
```

Also, the pointer pressed event handler is like this:

```
private void UserControl_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Focus(FocusState.Keyboard);
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: If you have resolved your issue please [mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) it as accepted to convenient people who visit this thread later.